# J1 visa with the “212 (e) rule does apply”

Tags: visas, usa, j1-visas

I have a J1 visa with the ''212 (e) rule does apply'' written below my visa but my visa is expired. Is it possible for me to enter the US? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 6):

The two year home country physical presence requirement does not mean you cannot travel to the US as a visitor. It does mean that you cannot work in or immigrate to the US during that time.

From the [US State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study/exchange/waiver-of-the-exchange-visitor/eligibility.html):

> It means you must return to your home country for a cumulative total period of at least two years. You are not prohibited from travelling to the United States. , However, you cannot do any of the following until you fulfull this requirement:
>
> - Change status in the United States to a nonimmigrant temporary worker (H) or intracompany transferee (L);
> - Adjust status in the United States to immigrant visa/lawful permanent resident status (LPR);
> - Receive an immigrant visa at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate; or
> - Receive a temporary worker (H), intracompany transferee (L), or fiancé (K) visa.
>
> There is a provision in U.S. law for a waiver of this requirement by the Department of Homeland Security (DHS), U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS). The former exchange visitor must apply for the waiver. The Department of State, Waiver Review Division must recommend the waiver to USCIS. Learn more about requesting a waiver.

*(errors in the original)*

Comment: But my visa is expired. Will I be allowed entry at the border?

Comment: You still need a valid visa. B1/B2 for a visit or an ESTA if your nationality supports it.